# What should be the effect of max-width on multiline flexbox's children?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This is a compatibility issue between **Safari** and Chrome/FireFox/Opera.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;                   /* establish flex container */
  flex-wrap: wrap;                 /* enable flex items to wrap */
}
.cell {
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.33% - 10px);   /* don't grow, don't shrink, width less margin */
  height: 50px;
  max-width: 50px; /* works only in Safari */
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #999;
}
.cell:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Safari output

[image]

Chrome / FireFox / Opera output

[image]

---

Browser | Version
--------|--------
Safari  | 9.1 (10601.5.17.4)
Chrome  | 51.0.2704.63 (64-bit)
FireFox | 46.0.1
Opera   | 37.0.2178.43

---

Standard doc http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/ didn't throw a light on use of max-width with multiline flex boxes except in the cross direction.

---

Reference: Issue came to light from discussion on [How do I create a 3x3 grid via CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502266/how-do-i-create-a-3x3-grid-via-css)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Safari.

As explained in the [***flexbugs repository***](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#11-min-and-max-size-declarations-are-ignored-when-wrapping-flex-items):

> Safari uses min/max width/height declarations for actually rendering the size of flex items, but it ignores those values when calculating how many items should be on a single line of a multi-line flex container. Instead, it simply uses the item's flex-basis value, or its width if the flex basis is set to auto.

I have found that using flex equivalents for min/max width/height declarations can work:

- [Flex items not stacking properly in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36636243/3597276)

The flexbugs document also offers a solution:

> The only way to avoid this issue is to make sure to set the flex basis to a value that is always going to be between (inclusively) the min and max size declarations. If using either a min or a max size declaration, set the flex basis to whatever that value is, if you're using both a min and a max size declaration, set the flex basis to a value that is somewhere in that range. This sometimes requires using percentage values or media queries to cover all possible scenarios.

References:

- [Min and max size declarations are ignored when wrapping flex items](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#11-min-and-max-size-declarations-are-ignored-when-wrapping-flex-items)
- [Bug 136041 - Safari (WebKit) doesn't wrap element within flex when width comes below min-width](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136041)