# Iphone 6 Safari Specific Flex-box Issue

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, flexbox

I have a wrapper which is flex-column content justified and aligned at center.
And inside that wrapper there are images. 
I over simplified the code and put somethings out, but issue is still going on. 
In only Iphone 6 flex column wraps all items on one line. 
Everywhere else Android,Windows,Mac and Iphone 5 and below this code works as it should.

**You should try this in the real device**, in simulator it works properly. 
I tried in several ios versions and Iphone 6's.

This is the CodePen link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/amgVLN

`I am sorry I didn't understand why CodePen links must follow with code?`

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35137085/3597276

Comment: Thank you i will check immediately.

Comment: I checked but i couldn't find anything iPhone 6 spesific, i tried your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36636613/6945542 but i need to use `max-width` and `max-height` with different values each. Do you have any advice spesific to this problem?

Comment: I'm really in need for assistance here if anybody saw this issue before.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have access to an iPhone 6 at this time.