# How can I make Flexbox work properly in safari 10

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I've been working on a website, now I got the feedback that it doesn't look like it's supposed to. I'm using flexbox and the problem occurs in Safari 10. I know this is an old browser, but according to http://caniuse.com/#search=flex it should be supported.

The problem occurs on the following page https://hollandcircularhotspot.nl/en/cases

I've searched entire stack overflow for the answers. I think I'm using the right prefixes, I'm not using a minimum width (which is a known issue).

The problem only occurs on safari 10 (as far as I am aware of)

This is how it looks on safari 10 https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTyqT.jpg
And this is how it is supposed to look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdcDh.jpg

Comment: Can we see your code? have a look at here [CLICK ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636243/flex-items-not-stacking-properly-in-safari)

Comment: you have to use display: flex; the property in the main class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change max-width to the width

```
.blocks-links .block-link, .blocks-links .block-link-big {
    color: #6F6F6F;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 21rem;
    /*max-width: 21rem;*/
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flexbox you can use `justify-content:` on the parent div and you can drop all of the media-queries that seem to be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```css
wrapper {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
}
```